# Add concerns module to Model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a model class called `Person`.
The person class has a attribute called `car`.

Now I would like to define a module in the concerns model called `Person::Car::HasProducer`

The module should look like that:

```
module HasProducer

   def produced_by_toyota?
     car == "Prius"
   end

   def produced_by_bmw?
     car == "X3" || car == "X5"
   end 
end
```

I would like to locate this file under: **concerns/person/car/has_producer.rb**

In the `Person`-class I tried to include it like that:

```
class Person
  include Person::Car::HasProducer
```

But there  I get the error: `Unable to autoload constant Person::Car::HasProducer`

I tried different combinations of `modules/classes` but none of the constellation worked for me.

**What do I have to do so that `has_producer.rb` get's found as `Person::Car::HasProducer`?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Either define your module to match the namespaces `Person::Car::HasProducer` i.e something like following:

```
class Person
  module Car
    module HashProducer
        # your code here
    end
  end
end
```

or just `include HasProducer`

Comment: Thanks for you comment, it worked by changing the first `module` to `class`. Great that you also noticed the `ActiveSupport::Concern`. I omitted it here in this example code. Please update your question and I will mark it as correct!